# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) when calling Core.inRange

Tags: opencv, android-studio

I am having an assertion error when using the Core.inRange function, actually any Core. function.  I have followed all solutions in the answers from similar questions.  Other solutions have been to check the number of channels, check if the image is empty and verify installation.  I am using Android Studio 2.2 on Mac.  Phones tested were ZTE Speed KitKat and Moto g3 Marshmallow.

My goal is to get the red and blue from an image -> determine if a Red light is On or a Blue one is on.  The code gets the image from a Vuforia Frame, converts it to a bitmap and then try to use OpenCV to manipulate the image.  This was working on previous code before we had to implement Vuforia as part of the core.

This is the main section of the code, the Imgproc.cvtColor function works fine, its the very last one Core.inRange

```
        Mat mat1 = new Mat(640,480, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Mat mat2 = new Mat(640,480, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Mat mat3 = new Mat(640,480, CvType.CV_8UC4);

        .......

        Log.d("OPENCV","Height " + rgb.getHeight() + " Width " + rgb.getWidth());

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb.getWidth(), rgb.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(rgb.getPixels());
        //Mat tmp = OCVUtils.bitmapToMat(bm, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Mat tmp = new Mat(rgb.getWidth(), rgb.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bm, tmp);

        SaveImage(tmp, "-raw");
        fileLogger.writeEvent("process()","Saved original file ");
        Log.d("OPENCV","CV_8UC4 Height " + tmp.height() + " Width " + tmp.width());
        Log.d("OPENCV","Channels " + tmp.channels());

        tmp.convertTo(mat1, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Size size = new Size(640,480);//the dst image size,e.g.100x100

        resize(mat1,mat1,size);//resize image
        SaveImage(mat1, "-convertcv_8uc4");
        Log.d("OPENCV","CV_8UC4 Height " + mat1.height() + " Width " + mat1.width());
        fileLogger.writeEvent("process()","converted to cv_8uc4");
        Log.d("OPENCV","Channels " + mat1.channels());

        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat1, mat2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);
        SaveImage(mat2, "-COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL");
        Log.d("OPENCV","COLOR_RGB2HSV Height " + mat2.height() + " Width " + mat2.width());
        Log.d("OPENCV","Channels " + mat2.channels());

        //Core.inRange(mat2, RED_LOWER_BOUNDS_HSV, RED_UPPER_BOUNDS_HSV, mat3);
        Log.d("OPENCV","mat2 Channels " + mat2.channels() + " empty " + mat2.empty());
        Log.d("OPENCV","mat3 Channels " + mat3.channels() + " empty " + mat3.empty());
        Core.inRange(mat2, new Scalar(0,100,150), new Scalar(22,255,255), mat3);
                    fileLogger.writeEvent("process()","Set Red window Limits: ");
        SaveImage(mat3, "-red limits");
```

These are the 2 errors I get when the command runs

```
       E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int), file /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 7349
       E/org.opencv.imgproc: imgproc::cvtColor_10() caught cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:7349: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int)
```

3 images are saved in the pictures directory as expected.

My logging produces the following

```
D/OPENCV: mat2 Channels 3 empty false
D/OPENCV: mat3 Channels 4 empty false
```

I have tried two different phones, tried adjusting the resolution down.  I have reinstalled the OpenCV module in case it was not installed correctly. I have made the images all 3 channels, all 4 channels.

Answer (score 0):

So after a week of debugging it was the most stupidest of mistakes!
Within the SaveImage function
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mIntermediateMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);
This was what was causing the issue.
After the Core.inRange was the SaveImage function.  Core.inRange dropped the channels to 1 - the fileLogger did not flush the last log, If I had used Log instead I probably would have picked it quicker.

```
public void SaveImage (Mat mat, String info) {
    Mat mIntermediateMat = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mIntermediateMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);  <--Here bad

    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String filename = "ian" + info + ".png";
    File file = new File(path, filename);

    Boolean bool = null;
    filename = file.toString();
    bool = Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, mIntermediateMat);

    if (bool == true)
        Log.d("filesave", "SUCCESS writing image to external storage");
    else
        Log.d("filesave", "Fail writing image to external storage");
}
```